# How to create an electric fence for slugs and snails using a car battery

Tags: battery-operated, current-limiting, shock

There are electric fences that are made using a regular 9v alkaline battery and two wires. One wire connects to the positive terminal, the other wire to the negative, and they are wrapped around the perimeter of a raised garden bed with minimal space in between the two wires. When a slugs body touches both the positive and the negative terminal, they receive a non-lethal shock and turn around.

Is it possible to make this same non-lethal fence using a larger battery? Like a car battery?

Do you simply use resistors to limit the current? Or are there other important factors such as voltage that have to be considered in order to deliver a non-lethal shock?

Also, based on my understanding, in electric fences for horses and cattle, etc. the fence is created using only the positive wire, while the negative wire goes to the ground. This makes the positive wire able to deliver a shock without there having to be contact with a second wire. Could a slug/snail fence be setup in this same manner?

When creating a fence with a larger power supply, does the gauge of the wire being used affect the shock that the slug would receive? For instance, could a wire or bar that is thick enough to be repeatedly driven over be used?

Could the Fence be set up directly on asphalt?

Could you power an electric fence like this using wall electricity?

Thank you for checking out my question. You can probably tell that I am not too experienced. I live in a monastery and we want to create a barrier around some vehicles that will shock insects, but not kill them. Our goal is to exclude as many insects as possible, to be non-lethal, and to be as maintenance free as possible.

[image: Text]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Also bear in mind that if you wheelbarrow some new soil in with slug / eggs(?) that they will breed and be trapped inside the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to make this same non-lethal fence using a larger battery? Like a car battery?

Yes. But...

**Edit: After some research, I have read that 12 volt batteries are at times lethal to slugs or snails. Since you want to avoid killing the slugs/snails, do not use a car battery. (Besides which, the current available from a car battery is far more than you need. The battery will probably discharge through internal leakage faster than it does from leakage between the fence wires.)**

...the fence will experience leakage current, particularly when it rains. To avoid having to recharge or replace batteries, I would recommend using a wall wart or other 9 volt supply. The current capacity of the supply (amperage) needs to be sufficient to handle the leakage current when it rains. Further, it would be nice if the supply has short circuit (overcurrent) protection. It is not easy to calculate the leakage current. It will depend on the length of the fence you wish to create, how often it rains, and the presence of soluble minerals. If you know the approximate length of your fence, I would multiply that length by say 5 mA per foot. I would then use a supply with a current capacity of that amount. So, if the fence were to be 100 ft, I would start with a supply that can deliver 500 mA, etc. When it rains, I would verify that the voltage across the wires is still 5V. If not, I would move to a larger power supply.

> Do you simply use resistors to limit the current? Or are there other important factors such as voltage that have to be considered in order to deliver a non-lethal shock?

9 volts is enough to give an unpleasant sensation to a slimy creature. If you touch both terminals of a charged 9 volt battery to your tongue, you will experience that unpleasant sensation. I quite imagine it would be enough to deter a slug or snail, although I have never attempted to create such a barrier. You could go to 12 volts.

> electric fences for horses and cattle, etc. the fence is created using only the positive wire, while the negative wire goes to the ground. This makes the positive wire able to deliver a shock without there having to be contact with a second wire. Could a slug/snail fence be setup in this same manner?

Not easily. Electric fences for cows and horses are designed for large animals. The live wire is separated from the ground by a significant distance. For slugs and snails, you need the live wire quite close to the ground wire (or the physical earth.)

> When creating a fence with a larger power supply, does the gauge of the wire being used affect the shock that the slug would receive? For instance, could a wire or bar that is thick enough to be repeatedly driven over be used?

> Could the Fence be set up directly on asphalt?

The wires can be as large as you like, to make them robust against accidental breakage. However they obviously must be uninsulated. You should do as shown in the picture. Have two wires closely spaced, so that the slug/snail has to touch both wires to get a "shock" (if shock it the right word for the sensation). You can lay them on asphalt, but I don't know how many times you can drive over a wire without it breaking or moving.

The wires should not be too thin, or you will have significant voltage drop when there is leakage current.

> Could you power an electric fence like this using wall electricity?

Do not use mains voltage directly, for multiple reasons. It is unnecessary to deter slugs and snails. 9 volts is sufficient. Mains voltage is too high and potentially fatal, not only to the snails and slugs but to humans, pets and other creatures. One wire from mains is already connected to ground, so the only wire you that would be useful is the live wire, and you don't want that lying about.

However, you can, and I suggest that you do, use a 9 or 12 volt supply that runs off of mains "wall" electricity, such as a wall wart.

> Our goal is to exclude as many insects as possible...

I'm not sure that this idea will be effective in deterring insects. Moisture of the organism's membrane that makes electrical contact is critical to the operation of this slug/snail electric fence. Touching the terminals of a 9 volt battery with one's dry fingers does not produce any sensation, but those same terminals in the mouth cause a "burning" sensation. Furthermore, even if 9 volts were unpleasant to a bug, how many bugs are large enough to touch both wires at once?

Comment: So, to clarify: If i use a wall wart, does the fence need both the positive and neutral wires to give the snails a shock? Or would I just connect a wire to the positive wall wart wire and surround the perimeter with that? Do wall warts limit the current sufficiently as well as dropping the voltage? Or would resistance be needed?

Comment: You will need two wires, as is shown in the image in your question. As far as I know, you do not need a resistor. However, I have read reports of slug electric fences occasionally killing worms. If that is a concern, you might try using a six volt power supply to see how that works. The amount of current you need, and whether a resistor would be a good idea depends a great deal on the length of the fence you want to make, whether the fence will be exposed to soluble minerals, which will become conductive when it rains, etc.  You have not specified your actual use case.